# Is there a way to cap a "displayed" value at an axis max/min while retaining the "actual" value for a tooltip display?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Most of you probably don't remember me from my previous question, [Circles not updating correctly for multiline charts with two-level nested data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69864791/d3-js-circles-not-updating-correctly-for-multiline-charts-with-two-level-nested). I managed to figure out/work around my issue there (although I still am not convinced that what I came up with is 100% correct); however, I now have another question.

My data has extreme outlier values. As a result, my charts get compressed, with quite a bit of blank space. See, for example, the "Cash Flow" chart in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/etonblue/a98m52k4/3/. I've tried various combinations of median, mean, average, std dev, etc., to try to set the domains, but haven't yet found a solution that works consistently for all of my data. So I've resorted to hard-coding my domains:

```
    if (val == 1) {ydom = [-2,20]}
        else if (val == 2) {ydom = [-40,240]}
        else if (val == 3) {ydom = [-.5,1.5]}
        else if (val == 4) {ydom =  [-.6,.9]}
        else if (val == 5) {ydom = [-.6,.6]}
        else if (val == 6) {ydom = [-.16,.16]}
        else if (val == 7) {ydom = [-.5,3]}
        else if (val == 8) {ydom = [-1000000,2000000]}
        else if (val == 9) {ydom = [-1000000,2000000]}
        else if (val == 10) {ydom = [-4,10]}
```

which is not only ugly, it also means that any extreme values are now either far above or far below my displayed y-axis.

My question, is there a way to use D3 to cap a **displayed** value at the max/min of a domain while retaining the **actual** value (so that a tooltip shows the actual value rather than the displayed value)?

I'm currently using d3.v4.

**UPDATE**
Pursuant to the the answer below, I revised my line function (and my "cy" attr function for the circles) thusly:

```
var line = d3.line()
    .x(d => x(d.year))
    .y(function(d) {
        val = document.querySelector('input[name="button"]:checked').value;
        if (val == 1) { if (d.mval < -2) {return y(-2)} else if (d.mval > 20) {return y(20)} else {return y(d.mval)}}
        else if (val == 2) { if (d.mval < -40) {return y(-40)} else if (d.mval > 240) {return y(240)} else {return y(d.mval)}}
        else if (val == 3) { if (d.mval < -.5) {return y(-.5)} else if (d.mval > 1.5) {return y(1.5)} else {return y(d.mval)}}
        else if (val == 4) { if (d.mval < -.6) {return y(-.6)} else if (d.mval > .9) {return y(.9)} else {return y(d.mval)}}
        else if (val == 5) { if (d.mval < -.6) {return y(-.6)} else if (d.mval > .6) {return y(.6)} else {return y(d.mval)}}
        else if (val == 6) { if (d.mval < -.16) {return y(-.16)} else if (d.mval > .16) {return y(.16)} else {return y(d.mval)}}
        else if (val == 7) { if (d.mval < -.5) {return y(-.5)} else if (d.mval > 3) {return y(3)} else {return y(d.mval)}}
        else if (val == 8) { if (d.mval < -1000000) {return y(-1000000)} else if (d.mval > 2000000) {return y(2000000)} else {return y(d.mval)}}
        else if (val == 9) { if (d.mval < -1000000) {return y(-1000000)} else if (d.mval > 2000000) {return y(2000000)} else {return y(d.mval)}}
        else if (val == 10) { if (d.mval < -4) {return y(-4)} else if (d.mval > 10) {return y(10)} else {return y(d.mval)}}
    })
```

Updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/etonblue/xwbkz98m/23/. As you can see in the updated fiddle, there are 9 radio buttons. The variable "val" identifies the active radio button, which determines the domain that is currently active and therefore which limits to check against.

If I am understanding it correctly, I think your updated answer will result in cleaner code. I will try to incorporate it.

However, I am now noticing yet another problem that probably warrants a separate question as I suspect it has to do with my update function. If you click the "Annual Enrollment Change %" function, you can see two green lines (without dots) at the bottom of the chart that are clearly left over from the "Current Ratio" chart. Ugh. It's always something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided isn't too relevant to the solution. Working from your fiddle, the solution is in your callbacks for the y positions of your line and circles. For your line:

```
var line = d3.line()
    .x(d => x(d.year))
    .y(d =>  d.mval > 240 ? y(240) : y(d.mval)) //If mval is over 240 plot 240
```

Likewise for your circles cy:

```
.attr('cy', d =>  d.mval > 240 ? y(240) : y(d.mval))
```

More Generally, you could use the callback:

```
d => d.mval > y.domain()[1] ? y(y.domain()[1]) : y(d.mval)
```

I don't quit understand your setup,

Comment: The solution is in SmokeyShakers' updated answer and it is indeed both "clean" and the "d3 way." See edited post above.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not just the clamp() option you need for a d3 scale? That would stop the domain --> range conversion exceeding the min/max of the range.

https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous_clamp